# How to send HTTP 500 status code in SOAP message

Tags: c#, xml, soap

I have a big,big,big problem.......

I'm coding in C#, I have to send SOAP message to server, it has to bee a message with code 500
This is the soap message that I'm sending:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap=""http:=""//schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"" xmlns:xsi=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"" xmlns:xsd=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"">
<soap:Body>
  <Code>500</Code>
  <Response_status>1</Response_status>
  <Description> SOME ERROR</Description>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

This message is a error message

The programmer on the other side tells me that he receives a message but that I have to change HTTP status code, he seas that he gets a HTTP/1.1 200 OK from his server but it has to be HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error.The message is OK but I'm missing HTTP/1.1 500.

Do I have to code it in my code or i have to write it in soap envelope I rely don't know how to write this so please help me if you can....

Thanks in-front!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution: in catch exception part of the code has to be this: base.Context.Response.StatusCode = 500; and then soap response, I have tried it and it works!

Answer (score 1):

> I have to send SOAP message to server, it has to bee a message with code 500

This doesn't make sense. The status code is sent by the server in response to the client's request. If the server sends a `200 OK`, your request was correctly formatted and processed.

Comment: No listen, i have a asmx service, and if the clinet sends me some data and if error o cures on my side I have to send the clinet code 500 in soap message, the message mention above, the programmer on other side said that the message is good but he didn't received code 500, when he does receive it he will send another message with data to me after some time

Comment: @CrBruno it's still not clear to me whether you are coding the client or the server side. A client cannot set a HTTP status code, the server does that. If this question is about how to set a certain value in a SOAP message, ask the vendor for the schema of the message (i.e. where in the message (header/body/HTTP header) to set it). If you want your ASMX SOAP service to return a 500 status code, then seach the web for that. If you want to return a SOAP fault, see for example [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7896284/asmx-not-throwing-soap-faults).

Comment: I'm the client and the server, my asmx web service directly writes data into the data base, but if there is an error in the process my service has to send back a code 500 using SOAP message

Comment: The solution: in catch exception part of the code has to be this: base.Context.Response.StatusCode = 500; and then soap response, I have tried it and it works!